# How to deduct the gamma function with fractional number?can we let term $k$ disappear?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, gamma-function

I am thinking about the problem :\begin{equation}
\frac{\Gamma(\alpha k+1)}{\Gamma(\alpha k-\alpha+1)}
\end{equation}

I know gamma function can represent as a series:\begin{equation}
\Gamma(x)=x^{x-1} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\binom{x}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^k \frac{k !}{k^k}\binom{n}{k}
\end{equation}
but i stucked as thinking: can we cancel term $k$ to simplify ?

Answer (score 0):

In *general*, you cannot simplify the expression but you can do is to take logarithms, use twice Stirling approximation, continue with Taylor series, exponentiate.

This would give
$$\frac{\Gamma(\alpha k+1)}{\Gamma(\alpha k-\alpha+1)}=(\alpha  k)^{\alpha }\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{P_n(\alpha)}{c_n\, k^n} $$  where the $c_n$ form sequence $A053657$ in $OEIS$.

The first polynomials $P_n(\alpha)$ are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & P_n(\alpha) \\
 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 1-\alpha  \\
 2 & \frac{(\alpha -2) (\alpha -1) (3 \alpha -1)}{\alpha } \\
 3 & -\frac{(\alpha -3) (\alpha -2) (\alpha -1)^2}{\alpha } \\
 4 & \frac{(\alpha -4) (\alpha -3) (\alpha -2) (\alpha -1) \left(15
   \alpha ^3-30 \alpha ^2+5 \alpha +2\right)}{\alpha ^3}\\
 5 & -\frac{(\alpha -5) (\alpha -4) (\alpha -3) (\alpha -2) (\alpha
   -1)^2 \left(3 \alpha ^2-7 \alpha -2\right)}{\alpha ^3}\\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Trying for $\alpha=\pi$ and $k=10$, the above truncated formula gives $\color{red}{45245.147961}69$